# What does you are getting reamed mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, american-english, slang

Ms C is accusing Ms Z of eating the cheese that Ms C bought. Ms C and Ms Z are room mates. Ms C sees a therapist about it.

> Ms Z: I don't eat that kind of cheese.
>
> Ms C: You do eat that kind of cheese. Every time I buy it, it disappears. My therapist told me that I have to stop letting someone take advantage of me.
>
> Ms Z: How much does your therapist charge you?
>
> Ms. C: 425 an hour.
>
> Ms. Z: You are getting **reamed** because I do not eat that kind of cheese.

What does Ms. Z mean by *reamed* in the last line?

**----------**

[Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ream) has this entry for *ream* as a verb:

> **ream** *transitive verb* **1a :** to widen the opening of (a hole) : countersink **b(1) :** to enlarge, shape, or smooth out (a hole) with a reamer **(2) :** to enlarge the bore of (something, such as a gun) in this way **c :** to remove by reaming **2a :** to press out with a reamer **b :** to press out the juice of (a fruit, such as an orange) with a reamer **3 :** cheat, victimize
> **4 :** reprimand —often used with *out* // *reams out his players so severely*— Alexander Wolff

The "cheat, victimize" meaning seems to be the best fit for the context here, but what is its connection to the earlier meanings of *ream* that Merriam-Webster lists?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ream

Comment: Are you sure ? I'm guessing its meaning is are cheated or something. Thanks

Comment: It's like being screwed, but with a bladed scrapey device that enlarges the hole in the manner of a planing tool" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reamer#/media/File:Taper_reamer_K-442.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ream as a Slang means *to cheat*
So here, Ms. Z is implying that the therapist is taking advantage of Ms. C and cheating her monetarily .

Comment: To add to the answer from @Niyanta, a reamer is a precision cutting tool, so "being reamed" has a similar meaning to "being skinned", hence being stripped of your assets.

Comment: Reamers are not used for stripping off anything external/convex; they are for expanding a _hole_.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock, I knew that: that's why I said 'cutting tool' [which is fairly general] and 'similar'.  If someone took a reamer to your body, it would feel like being skinned, I imagine.

Comment: I think you are being euphemistic; I suppose you thought I was being crude. Having done mechanical work, I like to be specific in describing tools. An awl is not like an adze, nor a spokeshave, nor a ripsaw, just because they all have sharp edges.

Comment: "Reamed" means "fucked" or "screwed".  In the above context that would imply being overcharged, but in a different context it could imply, eg, being sued frivolously.

Comment: I've just realized that I was probably thinking of a *router* [not in the comms sense] rather than a reamer.  Sorry, Brian.

Answer (score 5):

A *reamer* is a device or object that enlarges a hole, as this definition from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2013) indicates:

> **reamer** *n* (1825) **:** one that reams, as **a :** a rotating finishing tool with cutting edges used to enlarge or shape a hole **b :** a fruit juice extractor with a ridged and pointed center rising from a shallow dish.

For its part the verb *ream* has these meanings (according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*):

> **ream** *vt* (1815) **1 a :** to widen the opening (of a hole) : COUNTERSINK **b** (1) **:** to enlarge or smooth out (a hole) with a reamer (2) : to enlarge the bore of (as a gun) in this way c : to remove by reaming **2 a :** to press out with a reamer **b :** to press out the juice of (as an orange) with a reamer **3 :** CHEAT, VICTIMIZE **4 :** REPRIMAND — often used with *out*

What's missing from this description is how reaming in the sense of enlarging a hole applies to human beings. In *The Clouds*, Aristophanes indicates that in the Age of Pericles, adultery could be punished by subjecting the (male) adulterer to being "[reamed with a radish](http://bingweb.binghamton.edu/%7Eclas381a/study_guides/aristophanes_clouds_study-guide.htm)." The technical term for this punishment, apparently, is [*rhaphanidosis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhaphanidosis).

Here is a [translation (from 2000)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UqdFdo8RcJcC&pg=PA73&dq=rectal+radish+ramming&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QlA3Vd6YIdC1ogSi2ICwCQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=rectal%20radish%20ramming&f=false) of the relevant argument between Superior Argument and Inferior Argument in *The Clouds*:

> INFERIOR. Now, let us move on and discuss the needs of human nature. Suppose that you've been indulging in an illicit love affair. You are discovered! A scandal! What will you do? You are finished because you don't have the means to argue your way out of trouble. But if you choose to make my acquaintance, your nature can run free, with a spring in your step and a smile on your face, and shameful thoughts will never cross your mind. If the husband accuses you of adultery, plead innocence and blame Zeus. Say that clearly he can't resist his lust for women, so how can you, a mere mortal, be expected to have more strength than a god?
>
> SUPERIOR. Yes, but what if he takes your advice and gets punished by pubic plucking, scrotal singeing, and a jolly good **rectal radish ramming**. No argument of yours is going to help him after that.

The rather vague term "getting reamed" may have its roots (so to speak) in an allusion to this form of punishment, or to something like it.

Comment: Fascinating research and exposition.

Answer (score 3):

"Getting reamed", is slang for being fucked hard, in one hole or another. It is just a grosser, more exaggerated form of the slang "getting screwed", meaning to be taken advantage of, mistreated or abused.